# Show/Hide icon toggle in password input field

Tags: javascript, html, forms, show-hide

I have a simple HTML login form:

```js
const passwordField = document.querySelector("#password");
const eyeIcon = document.querySelector("#eye");

eye.addEventListener("click", function() {
  this.classList.toggle("fa-eye-slash");
  const type = passwordField.getAttribute("type") === "password" ? "text" : "password";
  passwordField.setAttribute("type", type);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/6d0b0e6586.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@200;400;500;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="login-flow">
  <section>
    <h1>Welcome back.</h1>
    <form action="#" method="post">
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <div class="password-container">
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" required>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-eye" id="eye"></i>
      </div>
      <!--pass-toggle-->
      <button type="button" name="btn" id="btn-login">Login</button>
    </form>
    <div class="form-footer">
      <p>Don't have an account? Create one <a href="register.html">here</a>.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</div><!--login-flow-->
```

Everything works great *except* the icon toggle. There are no warnings and the password input field changes between password and text in the console but the icon does not change. Interestingly, if I add the `fa-eye-slash` class to the `<i>` in `.password-container`, and `this.classList.toggle` to `fa-eye`, it works perfectly. It’s just that the icons are reversed. Why won’t it work as is?

Comment: Your Font Awesome classes only make sense if there’s _either_ `fa-eye` _or_ `fa-eye-slash` there, not both; otherwise one set of CSS rules will always override the other one. Why not add another `this.classList.toggle("fa-eye");`?

Comment: Thanks Sebastian. Can you explain a bit further? In the <i> tag, I'm only using one FA class, fa-eye, not both. The this.classList.toggle("fa-eye-slash"); is supposed to swap with the fa-eye icon. No?

Comment: _“The this.classList.toggle("fa-eye-slash"); is supposed to swap with the fa-eye icon. No?”_ — No, of course not! Why should it? Those are two completely unrelated classes.

Comment: Whey then, if the classes are swapped. . .if the <i> tag has the fa-eye-slash class and the this.classList.toggle("fa-eye"); , do they swap? They are still unrelated. What am I missing?

Comment: Not quite sure what you’re asking here, but you basically have classes A and B. If you want to change (only) A to (only) B, you have to toggle A (thus removing A) _and_ toggle B (thus adding B).

Comment: Let me clarify, currently the fa class for the <i> tag is fa-eye. However, if I change it to fa-eye-slash and change the this.classList.toggle to fa-eye, the toggle happens perfectly between the two on click. What's causing the rub is why it won't work as is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249211/discussion-between-thistlefinch-and-sebastian-simon).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you attached the event listener to a non-existing variable. try this

```
eyeIcon.addEventListener("click", function() {
  this.classList.toggle("fa-eye-slash");
  const type = passwordField.getAttribute("type") === "password" ? "text" : "password";
  passwordField.setAttribute("type", type);
})
```

Comment: That’s more of a comment than an answer. It’s correct: `eye` should be `eyeIcon` there. It works because it’s a global property: [Do DOM tree elements with ids become global properties?](/q/3434278/4642212). But this doesn’t answer the question.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I will strive to do better in the future

Comment: Thanks Mprizzuto. Adding eye in front of addEventListener doesn't attach it to the correct variable, the const with querySelector #eye?

Comment: @Thistlefinch Your variable is called `eyeIcon`, not `eye`.

Comment: Thanks gang. My variable is indeed eyeIcon, missed that one! Still not quite right.

Comment: Got it. Sebastian's suggestion of adding a second this.classList.toggle and your input on the incorrect variable were the issues. Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

here is your solution

```
eye.addEventListener("click", function() {

  const type = passwordField.getAttribute("type") === "password" ? "text" : "password";
  passwordField.setAttribute("type", type);

   if (passwordField.getAttribute("type") === "password") {
        eyeIcon.classList.remove("fa fa-eye");
        eyeIcon.classList.add("fa fa-eye-slash");
   } else {
        eyeIcon.classList.remove("fa fa-eye-slash");
        eyeIcon.classList.add("fa fa-eye");
   }
})
```